# How to generate correct RSA key for signing JWT?

Tags: go, openssl, jwt, asn.1

I'm using [this example](https://gist.github.com/thealexcons/4ecc09d50e6b9b3ff4e2408e910beb22), however it is slightly outdated. So, for, example `SignedString(key)`, I guess, receives `*rsa.PublicKey` instead of `[]byte` in case of RS256 signing method. I generated my private key using

```
openssl genrsa -out key.rsa 1024
```

And now trying to parse it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func main() {
    pem := []byte(`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)

    key, err := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(pem)
    fmt.Println(key, err)
}
```

But I get `asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:1 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} tbsCertificate @2` in response.

Is my key generating command somehow wrong? What should I read to be able to debug this? What asn1 has to do with it? Key has some particular syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `RSA PRIVATE KEY` but calling `jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM`. You should be calling `jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  OMG, how I missed something as obvious as this!